# How to color console output of a custom program

Tags: terminal, pipe, output, cts

### Problem:

I'm using Terminator but I think this question is relevant to any terminal.
To be more precise let me please explain my problem on concrete example.
I'm running Android cts tests, so I need to use cts-tradef script. This is how it looks like:

[image]

The script just runs jar (which I don't want to modify), however I would like to change color of cts-tf, so it looks like on a picture below:

[image]

### My unsuccessful attempts to solve the problem:

For now I've tried doing something like this:

```
echo -e "\033[01;32m" && ./cts-tradefed
```

However it will color everything (as on below picture) while I want to color only cts-tf string (as above):

[image]

I also tried using *sed*, however although it works and replace some strings it also finishes cts-tradefed, so it's useless to me. Same thing (cts-tradefed finishes) happens when piping it through *grep*:

```
./cts-tradefed | grep --color "cts-tf\|$"
```

Another try was with *grc* tool mentioned by **Anthony Geoghegan**. Running it without config file doesn't do anything but cts-tradefed doesn't finish but when I run it with config file cts-tradefed finishes the same as with *grep* or *sed*. My config file was ok, since it works good with *cat* or similar commands.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t used it myself but Radovan Garabík’s [Generic Colouriser](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html) looks like it should do what you want. It’s written in Python “for beautifying your logfiles or output of commands”.

Packages are available for Debian-based operating systems but I imagine it should not be too hard to install if you are familiar with Python.

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/garabik/grc)

Comment: Thanks, I've checked it and although it works for cat or similar it has same effect as piping through grep (cts-tradefed finishes). I can't accept your answer but it was useful, so I'll give +1.

Comment: @LLL That's cool. I upvoted your question because I thought it was a useful one. I must actually install `grc` myself. II regularly use the MySQL command line client and configuring a coloured prompt (using its native prompt variable) greatly enhances its usability, .e.g., red indicates I'm connected to a production server.